# why 'this._obj['a']=2' for setter doesn't work in Dart Class

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class Point {
 var obj ={};
 get _obj => obj;
 set _obj(v){
   print('active!$v');
   obj=v;
 }
 setObj(){
   this._obj={'a':1};   // it's work print  active!{a: 1};
   this._obj['a']=2;    // it does't work  no print ;  why>?
  } 
}



void main() {
  Point().setObj();
}
```

Why doesn't he no work?
i guess Dart different from the Js with Class prototype..

Comment: Can you add more description about this

Comment: Thanks! I've described it in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using this code:

```dart
this._obj={'a':1};
```

you are invoking the custom setter:

```dart
set _obj(v){
   print('active!$v');
   obj=v;
 }
```

but while using following approach:

```dart
this._obj['a']=2;
```

you are accessing the map. which does not have your custom implementation of `print('active!$v')` line.

you can try following code in dart pad to see how values are updated.:

```dart
class Point {
 var obj ={};
 get _obj => obj;
 set _obj(v){
   print('active!$v');
   obj=v;
 }
 setObj(){
   this._obj={'a':1};   // it works by replacing whole map using custom setter
   print(_obj);
   this._obj['a']=2;    // it works by accessing map values
   print(_obj);
  } 
}
```

Also, custom setter replaces your whole `obj` map, while `_obj['a']` updates only the value assigned to `a` key inside you map.

Comment: thanks!  How do I use  'this._obj['a']=2'   active  '  set _obj(v){
   print('active!$v');
   obj=v;
 }'   ？       i want   'this._obj['a']=2'    print    print('active!$v');

Comment: You can not override `[]` operator in map. but you can make a method which uses the operator internally and use that method to set values instead of `[]`. Something like this. 
`void setValue(key, value){ 
  print('$key: $value');
  _obj[key] = value; 
}`